# checking if enough elements in a F# list

Tags: f#

Right now I have a few instances like this:

```
let doIt someList =

    if someList |> List.truncate 2 |> List.length >= 2 then
        someList[0] + someList[1]
    else
        0
```

I need to grab the top 2 elements of a list quite often to see changes, but in some cases I don't have enough elements and I need to make sure there are at least 2.
The best way I've found so far is to truncate the list before getting its length, but this creates allocations for no reason.

Is there a better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would suggest pattern matching in this case:

```
let doIt someList =
    match someList with
    | a :: b :: _ -> a + b
    | _ -> 0
```

Here, `a` and `b` are the `int`s in the list, while `_` represents a discarded of `list int`. This way you don't have to pull the first two elements out of the list with an index, as they are already available as `a` and `b`. The last case of the `match` catches any pattern that was not matched earlier, such as cases with zero, one or three-or-more elements.

This should be a cheap operation, as F# lists are implemented as a singly linked list. So `[a;b;c;d]` would be represented as `a::(b::(c::(d::[])))`. `a` and `b` are matched, while the rest `(c::(d::[]))` is left untouched (and is put in the `_` slot). It does not need to create a new list to do so.

Comment: the List.Length will take considerably longer to execute when the list has thousands of elements in it, which is why I truncate it. but the match should work well, let me test that

Comment: Ah, that does make sense, now that I think about it. It needs to count all elements, whereas the first two elements are sufficient. I'll remove that part, if anyone reads this in the future, they'll use the match directly.